# How can I port a Google Chrome extension to Firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox-addon

One of my extensions has enjoyed popularity on Google Chrome and I would like to share that with Firefox users.  How can I convert the javascript from using chrome's API to something Firefox can handle?

Answer (score 1):

Extension factory will give you issues with the extension , just try it out but it will not convert it in a 100% working condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert Google Chrome extensions to Firefox and Safari using [Extension Factory](http://gallery.extensionfactory.com/labs/conversion/).